# Как отрисовать список(массив) в ReactJS?

Tags: массивы, reactjs

Начал недавно изучать реакт, по ролику Ulbi TV. В ролике он показывал, что можно использовать `Array.map()` для вывода данных списком (аналог v-for в Vue). Так я с точностью повторил его код (упрощаю его тут, тк там он в разных компонентах. Но у меня WebStorm ругается (Expression statement is not assignment or call) а сам реакт выводит такую ошибку (в фрагмент пробовал оборачивать, ничего не изменилось. Сам ролик 21 года, может быть с выходом 18 версии что-то изменилось, но ничего связанного со списками не нашел (в офф документации написано использовать `map` вне `return` записывая его в переменную, но это же неудобно

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pqqi.png]

Вот код

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {title: "title 1", body: "body 1", id: 1},
    {title: "title 2", body: "body 2", id: 2},
    {title: "title 3", body: "body 3", id: 3},
  ])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.map(post => {
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод map должен возвращать элементы. Вы пропустили return внутри
JSX элемент должен быть обернуть в ОДИН тег `div, span и т.д.` Когда вы уверены, что ваш код прекрасно встроится в DOM, возвращаемые элементы можно обернуть в `<></>`

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {title: "title 1", body: "body 1", id: 1},
    {title: "title 2", body: "body 2", id: 2},
    {title: "title 3", body: "body 3", id: 3},
  ])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Спасибо, в видео такого не было, но теперь понятно, а это было введено недавно?

Comment: Да, лет так 5-7 назад )

Comment: Почитайте первоисточник, потом смотрите видео [https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. Даже в первоисточнике нет упоминания про return

Comment: @Daskis, подозреваю, что в видео были круглые скобки, а не фигурные. И только один элемент, а не два.

Comment: @Daskis, в первоисточнике не было return потому что там считают, что основы синтаксиса разработчик уже знает. https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics