# Цикл в return REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В идеале я хочу что бы компонент `TableRow` вывелось столько раз сколько элементов в `workers`. Но я не имею представления, каким образом в return можно написать цикл. `for, foreach` или `map`. выдает ошибки. В данном примере я просто хочу посмотреть что мне выдаеть `console.log(item)`.  спасайте

```
import React from 'react'
    import Footer from '../components/Footer'
    import { useState,useEffect} from 'react'
    import LoginedHeader from '../components/LoginedHeader'
    import TableRow from '../components/TableRow'
    import axios from "axios";


const HourlyRates = () => {
  const [workers,setworkers] = useState(null)
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{

    try {
      const res = axios.post("http://localhost:8080/hourlyRates",{
    }).then((response)=>{
      if(response.data){
        setworkers(response.data)
        console.log("++")
      }else{
        console.log("--")
      }
      setReady(true); // Проверка выполнена
  })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("purums")
    }


  },[])
  // const info  = async ()=> {
    

  // }


  return (
    <>

        <LoginedHeader/>
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr >
            <th>Mentor name</th>
            <th>Type of jobs</th>
            <th>Hourly rates</th>
            <th>Fixed fee</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>

            { isReady && workers.map(item=>{console.log(item) }) }
        <TableRow/>
          </tbody>

        </table>
        <Footer />

    </>
  )
}

export default HourlyRates
```

что храниться в woreks.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие ошибки выдает? Не эту ли [readind map of null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отрисовать список(массив) в ReactJS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453065/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-reactjs)

Comment: Что за данные в workers по итогу непонятно, если там прилетает объект, то в рендере {Object.keys(workers).map(item => <TableRow/>)}, если прилетает массив, то просто {workers.map(item => <TableRow/>)}

Comment: @SwaD workers.map is not a function

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть на тип данных, который приходит в workers. [Причины ошибки is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказали комментарии проблема была в типе приходящих данных.
проблема захардкодена следующим образом:

```
      Object.keys(workers[item]).map(item2 =>{
        console.log(workers[item][item2].job_name)
        {
        <TableRow
        firstName={workers[item][item2].firstName}
        lastName={workers[item][item2].lastName}
        job_name={workers[item][item2].job_name}
        hourly_rates = {workers[item][item2].hourly_rates}
        fixed_fee={workers[item][item2].fixed_fee}
        />
      }
      })
    })
  }
```