# Проблема с возвратом компонента в react. Помогите кто может

Tags: reactjs, typescript

хочу сделать что-то по типу списка фильмов, которые задаю в массиве, но не получается.[image: ошибка или белый фон]

всегда либо просто белый фон, либо он же, но только с ошибкой

App.jsx:

```
import './App.css'
import { AllView } from './AllView'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <AllView/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Массив, в котором содержится информация о фильмах:

```
export let filmsData = [
    {
        name: 'Death book', 
        year: 2007,
        censure: '16+',
        country: 'Japan',
        time: '145min'
    },
    {
        name: '1+1',
        year: 2012,
        censure: '12+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '120min'
    },
    {
        name: 'Gran Turismo',
        year: 2023,
        censure: '18+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '134min'
    },
    {
        name: 'Matrix',
        year: 1991,
        censure: '18+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '120min'
    }
]
```

Компонент, с которым как раз таки и проблемы:

```
import { filmsData } from './filmsData'

export function AllView() {
    return (
    function ChangeOutput(name, year, censure, country, time) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{name}</h3>
                <br />
                <h5>{year}</h5>
                <h5>{censure}</h5>
                <br />
                <h4>{country}</h4>
                <h4>{time}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function ChangeInput() {
        for (let i = 0; i < filmsData.length; i++) {
            ChangeOutput(filmsData[i].name, filmsData[i].year, filmsData[i].censure, filmsData[i].country, filmsData[i].time);
        }
    }

    ChangeInput();
    )
}
```

Comment: И не получится, ты какую-то муть пишешь. В return вообще функции и синтаксические ошибки. И сообщение об ошибке явно не для этого кода.

Comment: Я такого еще не видел... зачем функцию возвращать то? [Вот тут посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453065/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-reactjs/1453073#1453073), как список рисовать

Comment: @SwaD, для кода из вопроса было бы `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'function'`, а не то, что он говорит. Если он не умеет копипастить, и функции на самом деле не в return, то должно получиться что-то типа "из компонента нельзя возвращать undefined", а не то, что в вопросе. Ну если ещё скобочки вызова убрать, то ошибка сойдётся (при условии, что там импорт есть)... В общем, у меня ощущение, что это какой-то троллинг просто.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

меня очень смущает код компонента AllView, попробуй лучше так:

```js
import React from "react";

export let filmsData = [
    {
        name: 'Death book',
        year: 2007,
        censure: '16+',
        country: 'Japan',
        time: '145min'
    },
    {
        name: '1+1',
        year: 2012,
        censure: '12+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '120min'
    },
    {
        name: 'Gran Turismo',
        year: 2023,
        censure: '18+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '134min'
    },
    {
        name: 'Matrix',
        year: 1991,
        censure: '18+',
        country: 'USA',
        time: '120min'
    }
]

const ViewItem = (props) => {
    const { name, year, censure, country, time } = props;
    return <div>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <br/>
        <h5>{year}</h5>
        <h5>{censure}</h5>
        <br/>
        <h4>{country}</h4>
        <h4>{time}</h4>
    </div>
}

export default function AllView() {
    return (
        <div>
            {filmsData.map(film => <ViewItem key={film.name} film={film}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```